# Docker container from Angular4 app : "-p" : executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I want to create and run a Docker container for my **Angular 4** application.

I ve created the image :

```
docker build -t front:Angular4 -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile .
```

and i tried to create anbd run the container instance of my image using :

```
docker run --name frontcontainer -it front:Angular4 -p 4200:4300 -v /usr/share/nginx/logs:/usr/share/nginx/logs -P
```

this seems creating the container but **not running it**  . And it throws this error:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot start container
>   40613e12e254a433e2b5f774ffcab67be9c3027cef761141f63ec8fb03bfc108: [8]
>   System error: exec: "-p": executable file not found in $PATH

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

Step 1 :

You need to create docker file inside the project root.

```
- myApp/
    - Dockerfile
```

inside the Docker file add below code

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Step 2:

build your project in production mode

Step 3 :

```
docker login

docker build -t <your registry or image location> .

docker run --name <your project name > -d -p 4200:81 <your registry or image location>

docker push <your registry or image location>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is, I believe, telling you that you need to fix the syntax on your command.

The syntax (`docker run --help`) shows the syntax should be something like:

`docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND]`

So, something like below might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
docker run 
  -itP \
  --name frontcontainer \
  -p 4200:4300 \
  -v /usr/share/nginx/logs:/usr/share/nginx/logs \
  front:Angular4
```

Unrelated, but your first command isn't building the image. It's also a malformed `docker run` command and will probably also present an error.

Comment: Our Markdown engine is not GitHub-flavored. Triple-quotes are not special here; use four-space indents for multi-line code blocks.